# Windows WiFi network devices

Tags: c++, windows, wifi

I'm creating a WiFi program for Windows, I'm new to network programming.
I'm using the Native Wifi API to get information about a network but now I want information about the other devices that are connected to a network.

Does anybody know what I should learn to accomplish this? Do I need to use winsock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via UPnP (assuming your AP supports UPnP, but most do).

You'd connect to the `WLANConfiguration` service of your UPnP access point, and read the `TotalAssociations` to get the number of associated devices, and the  `AssociatedDeviceMACAddress` and/or `AssociatedDeviceIPAddress` variables to get the addresses of the associated devices. The latter might give you IPv4 or IPv6 addresses, or it might give you host names.

The `TotalAssociations` variable is "evented", which means you can have the access point tell you want the number of associated devices changes, and re-enumerate their addresses when that happens.

Microsoft also provides a [UPnP API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382303.aspx) that may be helpful (though I've never used it personally, so I can't say much more about it).

## References

1. [UPnP Architecture specification](http://upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf)
2. [WLAN Configuration Service specification](http://upnp.org/specs/gw/UPnP-gw-WLANConfiguration-v1-Service.pdf)